# How to get the last line from JSON file which contains only tuples in each line

Tags: python, python-3.x

can anybody pls tell me what way I need to use to fetch the last line from JSON file which contains tuples?

```
lst = (('7', '♠'), ('7', '♣')) # this line is generated each time and has new values
```

For instance, "deals.json" file contains such lines:

```
[["7", "\u2660"], ["7", "\u2663"]]
[["8", "\u2660"], ["8", "\u2663"]]
```

Code:

```
# here I add new line into the file
with open('deals.json', 'a') as f:
    json.dump(lst,f)
    f.write('\n')

# here I want to read the last line and handle it
with open('deals.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    print(json_data)
```

After running this code it works fine but after the 2nd one it failed while trying to read the file and it's obvious:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 549)
```

I know how to do that using text file but have no idea how to read the last line in JSON which contains tuples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading and parsing a JSON file with multiple JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451431/loading-and-parsing-a-json-file-with-multiple-json-objects)

Comment: @rchome partly. but I need to get only the last line w/o reading the whole file line by line because there are a lot lines in it. trying to find the say how to do it.... I will post the result a later

Comment: tuples are not valid json types, so your question is very confusing. could you be more precise?

Comment: @diggusbickus seems the question is quite clear. I need get only the last line from the JSON file. What exactly I need to note? I use such approach instead of TXT because it'd be easier to handle it but if it's impossible so I think it should be resolved using another way

Comment: @diggusbickus I used such solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64082441/save-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-file-and-read-it-again-as-a-list but I do not need to parse / read the whole JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading just the last line can be achieved like this. Internally the entire file will be read but you don't need to handle that explicitly. If the file was **very** large then you might need another approach.

```
import json
with open('deals.json') as f:
    j = json.loads(f.readlines()[-1])
    print(j)
```

**Output:**

```
[['8', '♠'], ['8', '♣']]
```

Comment: yep, that works fine. thx a lot for assistance. But I think it'd be better to use another approach like you suggested but anyway this works great for another task which I worked on